# Azure Pipeline - Exporting Terraform output as environment variable for subsequent stage

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, yaml

I've written a yaml script and run in Azure DevOps, and I would like to see if it is possible to set the output of the terraform apply stage as an environment variable and being used in subsequent stages. My script is like:

```
- stage1: Operation on state file 1
  jobs: 
     ...
          - bash: |
              terraform apply 'dev.plan'
```

````
- stage2: Operation on state file 2
  jobs:
     ...
          - bash: |
              terraform init
     ```
````

Appreciate a lot for any advice.

Tried to use the stagedependency.xx.xx feature in Azure DevOps with no luck. Not sure if this is the appropriate choice.

Comment: Have you tried to use the task.setvariable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash

Comment: @Ging Yuan-MSFT, yes I do, but it throws me an error: myVar: command not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow below steps:

1 store Terraform state in Azure storage. please refer to [Store Terraform State](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/store-state-in-azure-storage?tabs=azure-cli)

exampl.tf

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>2.0"
    }
  }
  backend "azurerm" {
        resource_group_name  = "your resource group name"
        storage_account_name = "your storage account name"
        container_name       = "your container name"
        key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
# this is important, you can get the remote outputs for this
output "password" {
  value = xxxxxx
}
```

2 use terraform command to print the output and you can see the output.

```
terraform output
```

3 configure output variable in azure pipeline
[image: configure output variable]

4 Create a PowerShell step in your pipeline and insert the following inline PowerShell:
[image: pipeline]

```
$json = Get-Content $env:jsonPath | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach($prop in $json.psobject.properties) {
    Write-Host("##vso[task.setvariable variable=$($prop.Name);]$($prop.Value.value)")
}
```

And remember to set environment variable `jsonPath`.

**update 5/12/2022**

You could use the command `task.setvariable` to set the output name(example:password) as an azure devops pipeline variable.

```
 echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=password]$(terraform output password)
```

YAML script Sample

```
stages:
- stage: stage1
  jobs:
   - job: A1
     steps:
     - task: Bash@3
       inputs:
         targetType: 'inline'
         script: |
           terraform apply 'dev.plan'
         workingDirectory: 'Directory containing the Terraform configuration file'
     - task: Bash@3
       inputs:
         targetType: 'inline'
         # terraform output 'your name'
         # your name is the name you defined in output.tf.Here is `password` example
         script: |
           terraform output password
         workingDirectory: 'Directory containing the Terraform configuration file'
- stage: stage2
  jobs:
  - job: A2
    steps:
      - task: Bash@3
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=password]$(terraform output password)
```

Comment: Appreciate a lot for your help. But I would prefer everything to be done in yaml script.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Hope it can help you.

Comment: @akaya_1992  Does it work for you ? If it helps, just a remind of accept an answer, this will help other users who has the same issue.

Comment: @DouXu-MSFT I used both alternatives. I am using yaml pipeline. The powershell one is giving me the error:  Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null. It highlights $env:jsonPath. Can you please tell me to what I need to set this value in my yaml pipeline. I also used your other solution to define the environment variable with ##vso, but the value is not set. terraform output <output-value> prints in the output of the pipeline, but as soon as I pass it, ##vso script seems not working, as the variable is not being taken in the same task and others.

Comment: @DouXu-MSFT In other pipelines, "##vso[task.setvariable variable=<variableName>]$(<variableValue>)" works, but in this case, it is not setting the value. I am running my terraform code inside a docker container in my Azure DevOps pipeline yaml in a job. Do you know by any chance why it is not working?